# AWS Statemachine Execution Status through aws Lambda( Python)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

i have to check whether a statemachine is in running or succeeded status through aws lambda function.
If it's not in running status, i will invoke the same statemachine in aws lambda . Tried this and its expecting executing ID of my statemachine. My first step is to get execution status and based on the status , i need to invoke/trigger the state machine. Is it possible to get the execution status using the StatemachineARN ?

```
response = client.describe_execution(
    executionArn='arn:aws:name')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`describe_execution` is not what you want.  It returns information about a specific State Machine execution.  A state machine [execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-state-machine-executions.html) *"occurs when an AWS Step Functions state machine runs and performs its tasks."*  Each execution run has its own ARN.

To get running executions for a (Standard) State Machine, call [list_executions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.list_executions):

```py
response = client.list_executions(
    stateMachineArn='string',
    statusFilter='RUNNING',
)
```